# Android - NullPointerEx. caused by getPackageName() from Android Library Class

Tags: java, android, gradle, nullpointerexception, android-library

I'm working on a project where I have to start an Activity inside an Android Library from the MainActivity in the normal 'app' module.

The MainActivity looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements BackendResponse {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

// Here I start an AsyncTask
public void tellJoke(View view) {
    BackendConnector backendConnector = new BackendConnector();
    backendConnector.execute();
}

// And here is the Callback 
@Override
public void response(String joke) {
    /*
        Down here is the problematic line (PresenterActivity is imported)
    */
    Intent jokeIntent = new Intent(this, PresenterActivity.class); // <--- line 18
    if (joke == null) joke = getString(R.string.emergency_joke); 

    jokeIntent.putExtra(getString(R.string.intent_key), joke);

    startActivity(jokeIntent);
}
```

In the *build.gradle* file from the 'app' module the dependency is set

```
android {
    // compileSdkVersion etc
}
dependency {
    compile project(':jokepresenter') // <--- 
}
```

And in the *settings.gradle* file from the whole project the library is included

```
include ':app', ':jokepresenter'
```

The *Logcat* says as follows:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
    Process: com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger, PID: 2723
    java.lang.NullPointerException: 
    Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
    // ...
    at com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.MainActivity.response(MainActivity.java:18)
    at com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.BackendConnector.onPostExecute(BackendConnector.java:53)
    at com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.BackendConnector.onPostExecute(BackendConnector.java:17)
    // ...
```

Comment: Could you maybe **tell** why you downvote the question? Maybe we could solve the problem?

Comment: try MainActivity.this or getContext() instead of only this in intent

Comment: MainActivity.this gives same error. And I can't call _getContext()_, only _getBaseContext()_ and _getApplicationContext()_ (and there's same error too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it.

The Problem was the Callback method or to be more specific inside the AsyncTask.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String joke) {
    response = new MainActivity(); // <--- ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
    response.response(joke);
}
```

Because I created a new MainActivity there was **no Context** represented by *this*:

```
Intent jokeIntent = new Intent(this, PresenterActivity.class);
```

Which lead to a *NullPointerException* inside the **ContextWrapper** when he tried to call

```
return mBase.getPackageName();
```

**mBase** was set as the Activity Context which was of course **null**